# Design of an Octave Band Filter

Tags: filter

The idea is that i will divide the frequency spectrum into octave bands (frequency band where the highest frequency is twice the lowest frequency) where the noise will be measured in each one of those octave bands, all at the same time.

The result should be something like this:

[image]

To implements this i'm thinking of making simple parallel pass-bands filters with determined centre frequencies, this is an example (top figure):

[image]

Now one thing that troubles me is that in my case i will need to develop a lot of pass bands filters, is there anyway to avoid this? If not i will need to apply the equation below ten times, same thing with the circuit.

[image]

After making those band pass filters i still need to do some more operations with the end result, an example is shown below. In my case i'm doing everything analog till this point.

[image]

Next problem is, after i implement those filters how do i exactly connect them to the rest of the circuit? So they will all end in the same point but afterwards how can i distinguish one band from the other and have something like the first image i put here? Cant short-circuits happen?

Comment: You don't have to do the full calculations ten times : if suffices to calculate one filter, and the other filters are identical, except that you multiply the capacitors by 2 from one filter to the next (assuming your filter are resistor-capacitor filters). You may also change the resistors only (or make a mix)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use analog filters, then you normally put an analog multiplexor before the ADC. The processor then quickly scans the inputs. Converting to LOG can be done by the processor.

What you have described is how people would do this 40 years ago. This is basically my college senior project.

The modern way to do this is to use a ADC to read the analog input directly, then do a fourier transform in software to separate the bands. Converting the bands to octaves is a little tricky, the output of the fourier transform is linear bands. I have done this also, but it is just a toy, it isn't calibrated.

Comment: Perhaps i could do everything in analog (weighting filter, peak detector/squaring circuit) and connect the output to multiple analog inputs of the MCU and divide the frequency spectrum into octave bands there? Would that still be possible after making the square part?

Comment: Yes, some MCUs have a built-in analog multiplexor.

Comment: Instead of FFT, use a cascade of [quadrature mirror filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_mirror_filter) to divide the frequency range into octave bands. Each additional filter pair sub-divides the low-pass output of the previous pair.